# In vue I have questions about database and lifecycle

Tags: vue.js, dhtmlx

I wrote a gantt chart using 'dhtmlxGantt' in vue. The data I want to put into the gantt chart is in my database, I get it by 'get' method and put it into a variable called 'data'.

If it is normal flow, you have to draw the event on the gantt chart on the screen with this data, but there is a problem here. The lifecycle section that fetches the data is called 'created', but no events are drawn on the screen. It has been determined that retrieving data from the database is successful.

I think the event that draws a chart on the screen first appears first, then the data is loaded. This is because there is nothing in the variable 'data' before the drawing event is applied to the screen.

How can I generate an event that draws a chart on the screen after the data is loaded? Is this a lifecycle matter? I wonder if anyone has a similar problem.

Comment: Try using the `mounted` hook instead of `created`